# Using pop function in multidimensional array AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, multidimensional-array

What I'd like to be able to do is make my function find the index of an array in my array list and delete it. I'd like it to find the first and last name of a person stored inside of an array stored in in it's two first slots (0 and 1) (ex: example[0]=["Robert", "Brown", 1000, 2100, 600, 400];) and delete it (the whole element[0]) from the list of my array. This is the list that I have right now:

```
voyageur[0]=["Roger", "Dagenais", 1000, 2100, 600, 400];
voyageur[1]=["Phil", "Thomas", 200, 300, 1400, 800];
voyageur[2]=["Nikolas", "Brideau", 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000];
```

Now let's say I want to delete Phil Thomas (element #1) from my array. How would I do it?

```
function supprimer(event:MouseEvent):void {

var indiceVoyageur:int;
var indiceVoyageurPrenom:int;
var indiceVoyageurNom:int;

if ( (boitePrenom.text != "") && (boiteNom.text != "") )
     {
        for (var rang:int = 0; rang < voyageur.length; rang++)
        {
        indiceVoyageurPrenom = (voyageur[rang][0].indexOf(boitePrenom.text));
        indiceVoyageurNom = (voyageur[rang][1].indexOf(boiteNom.text));

        if (indiceVoyageurPrenom != -1)
        {
            for (var i=indiceVoyageur; i <voyageur.length; i++)
            {
                voyageur[i] = voyageur[i+1];
            }
            voyageur.pop();
        }
        }
     }
  }
```

This is some code that I had made previously but it doesn't really work properly. If you have another way of doing what it is that I want to do, that would also be fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of shuffling and popping, you can just use `splice`:

```
function supprimer(): void {

    var indiceVoyageur: int;
    var indiceVoyageurPrenom: int;
    var indiceVoyageurNom: int;

    if ((boitePrenom.text != "") && (boiteNom.text != "")) {
        for (var rang: int = 0; rang < voyageur.length; rang++) {
            indiceVoyageurPrenom = (voyageur[rang][0].indexOf(boitePrenom.text));
            indiceVoyageurNom = (voyageur[rang][1].indexOf(boiteNom.text));

            if (indiceVoyageurPrenom != -1 && indiceVoyageurNom != -1) {
                voyageur.splice(rang, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand exactly your code as it seems to be with some strange variables.. But this should work:

```
function clear(firstName:String, lastName:String):Boolean {
    var total:uint = _users.length;
    // _users is a member variable of the users array
    // you can pass it to the function if you don't like it to be member

    var found:Boolean;

    for (var i:uint = 0; i < total; i++) {
        var data:Object = _users[i];

        if (data.indexOf(firstName) != -1 && data.indexOf(lastName) != -1) {
            data.splice(i, 1);
            i--; // keep searching for other items in the array
            found = true;
        }
    }

    return found; // return true if it finds it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will satisfy your need as to delete those elements and returns the output. no need of looping. directly use array methods max for optimization.

```
var voyageur1:Array=["Roger", "Dagenais", 1000, 2100, 600, 400];


var voyageur2:Array=["Phil", "Thomas", 200, 300, 1400, 800];

var voyageur3:Array=["Nikolas", "Brideau", 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000];

var voyageur4:Array=voyageur2.splice(0,2);

trace(voyageur4); //Phil,Thomas

trace(voyageur2); //200,300,1400,800[after deleting].
```

hope you expected this.